# what is the use of total in this query?

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
SELECT pg_size_pretty(pg_total_relation_size('my_table')) AS size;
```

Here in this query what is the use of pg_total_relation_size(),I tried without using total but it showing different size.Any one help me?

Comment: [From the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-admin.html): "*Total disk space used by the specified table, **including all indexes and TOAST data***"

Answer (score 0):

It includes the size of indexes and TOAST data too.